# На сайте нижний синий блок съехал, как его поправить?

Tags: html, css, joomla

http://fes-24.ru/proizvodstvo
Страница сайта, внизу есть блок, он съехал, как его поправить, сайт на cms joomla, там неудобный интерфейс, помимо самого материала, есть отдельный файл оформления как я понял, его я найти не могу, на других страницах я просто через 
 сдвигал чтоб блок лег ровнее, а вот как поступить тут?

Comment: У вас там белый текст на белом фоне? Или это только у меня?

Comment: Если убрать отрицательный margin-top у футера, он выглядит лучше)

Comment: Там еще и футер находится в контенте. Непонятно зачем, но ...

Comment: Да на белом фоне белый текст, синий блок как раз для него)

Comment: Я лишь вношу правки по сайту, я не прикладывал к нему свои руки >_>